# What's the meaning behind the nickname that "the board" has for David?

Tags: character, vanilla-sky

In *Vanilla Sky*, Thomas Tipp tells David that the board (a.k.a, the seven dwarfs) has a nickname for David -- "Citizen Dildo".

I've seen this film many times and the only curiosity I'm always left with is the meaning behind this nickname. The only thing I can think of is maybe it's related to how David doesn't take his work seriously, and/or all he does is try to please everyone [and therefore is being used by others for pleasure/entertainment].

Is there a concrete meaning behind this nickname? Is it maybe a play-off of some other phrase / common nickname?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a reference to his philandering ways among "commoners".  David is heir to a fortune, yet he spends most of his time having sex with women who aren't in the upper crust of society.  In effect, he is a "dildo" to "citizen" women.

I have to admit, at first I thought it was a play on "Citizen Kane", but there really aren't any similarities between Charles Kane and David Aames beyond the fact that they both inherited their fortunes.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I think it’s Cameron Crowe just throwing an Easter Egg from his film [*Singles*](https://imdb.com/title/tt0105415/) where the band was called “Citizen Dick”